# ANOVA to correlate two variables

Tags: correlation, anova

I have a question about if its is possible to determine the correlation between  two variables using ANOVA. Could you give me some guide about it? I know that usually Pearson or Spearman Analysis are used, but ANOVA? In my case I need to correlate the scores in tests in a language A with the scores in tests in a language B.